# Unable to search using Loopback API

Tags: node.js, db2, loopbackjs

I am using nodejs with LoopBack api, DB2 as database.

I have already discover my existing schema from my existing db.

What I want to do is to do is to check the value of item id that begins with 'Z'.

```
'use strict';

//imports
var Task1 = function () {};

Task1.prototype.generateList = function (app, cb) {

    var Book = app.models.Book; 

    var pattern = new RegExp('/^Z.*$/', "i"); /* case-insensitive RegExp search */

    Book.find({where: {id: {regexp: pattern}}}, function(err, books) { 
        console.log(books);
    });

    console.log("task1!");
};

module.exports = Task1;
```

I am followingto the api doc below.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html#like-and-nlike-insensitive

Am i doing my query correctly or am i missing of so other information?

Comment: Is without `regex` , your query return all data?

Comment: @IftekharDani u mean like this Book.find({where: {id: {}}} ... ?

Comment: Just check `Book.find({})`

Comment: @IftekharDani yes it is returning me all the records.

Answer (score 0):

Reference Link : https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html

Please check :

```
Book.find({where: {id: {regexp:/^Z.*$/i}}}, function(err, books) { 
        console.log(books);
    });
```